# meteor spacebars run a helper whose name is available as a string in context

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I am using meteor 1.4 for building a real time task assignment app.
I am stuck at a point when i want to include a template passing in an argument the template helper of that template to run.

Now when i pass the argument, it is passed as a string and i want to call that template helper. But i cannot find any way in spacebars to call a template helper when i have the helper name available as a context variable of string type.

Please tell whether it is possible and if yes, then how ??

Thanks in advance

Edit 1 - For ex.

```
<template name="parent">
    {{> children helperParameter="someHelper"}}
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{> child2 value=helperParameter }}
</template>

<template name="innerchild">
    {{value}}
</template>
```

So basically, I want to pass the value returned by someHelper to the template innerchild and i want to decide which helper (in this case someHelper) to run in child by passing the name of that helper to child template from parent template.

Now, i can not run that helper in child template where i have its name in parameter helperParameter as a string.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Instead of picking a helper by it's name (which is not possible in spacebars), you could have a "stub" helper which looks at the value from your context and chooses the right implementation based on that. Do you think that this would solve your problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example code ??

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Template.dynamic`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-dynamic).

```html
<template name="layout">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=template}}
    <!-- This is equivalent to
    {{> nameOfNeededTemplate}}
    -->
</template>
```

```js
Template.layout.helpers({
  template: function() {
    return 'nameOfNeededTemplate';
  }
});
```